# Long.parseLong error when parsing a string from a SAXparser class (Java)

Tags: java, parsing, runtime-error, saxparser

I have a problem but I don't know how to solve it:
I need to get a Long number from a String (I get this string in a SAXparser class I wrote to get some fields from an XML file).

Here you are the problematic code:

```
if (bprice) {
String price = new String(ch, start, length);
System.out.println("Product price: " + price);
bprice = false;
if (price.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))
product.price = null;
else product.price = Long.parseLong(price);
}
```

(**product** is an instance from an object where I store all the product information. I got the error in the last line)

I debugged it and I got this:

> > Exception occurred in target VM: For input string: "1.04"  java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.04"     at
> >     java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
> >       at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:419)  at
> >     java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)   at
> >     parsers.LectorXML.characters(LectorXML.java:325)  at
> >     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.characters(AbstractSAXParser.java:538)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:464)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
> >       at
> >     com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1205)
> >       at parsers.LectorXML.leer(LectorXML.java:71)    at
> >     parsers.LeerXML.main(LeerXML.java:20) <

Comment: What's your question? It's quite obvious that 1.04 is not a valid long number.

Comment: You should not use `long` or floating point numbers to store prices, unless the prices are expressed in cents (104 instead of 1.04). The most precise type for storing monetary data is [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight what's about `Double`?

Comment: @Alberto `Double` will accumulate errors when you do math with it because its representation of decimal fractions is not precise.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @dasblinkenlight. I changed my code this morning and I am using `BigDecimal` instead `Double` for the prices. I experienced it is slower than working with `Double`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.04 is not a valid long. It is in double format.

You need to use [Double.parseDouble(String);](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29) instead.

Example:

```
Double.parseDouble(precio1);
```

Comment: Oh my god!!! After 6 hours coding I didn't see that!! Ohhhhhh damn it! haha. I'm soooooooooooooo sorry for my stupid question... :(. Thank you very much @Nambari

Comment: I tried to accept it but I still had to wait 11 minutes when I tried to (still 4 minutes from now to be able to accept it).
I am going to have dinner and I will accept it after that, ok? Thank you very much and I am sorry again!

Comment: @Alberto: That was just regular note because you are new user to SO. No force (or) time lines on accepting answers.